# Can't rename file through SFTP even though user has permissions

Tags: windows, ssh, permissions, sftp

I have two computers both running Windows 10.

Computer A is running an ssh server, and computer B tries to connect through sftp.

I have the sshd_config set as follows:

```
Subsystem   sftp    sftp-server.exe

AllowUsers test
ForceCommand internal-sftp
ChrootDirectory "E:\MyData"
```

User `test` doesn't belong to any group.

Inside `E:\MyData` there is a file named `test.txt`, and user `test` has permissions to read, write and modify it on computer A.

Connecting through sftp works fine, and I can read the file properly. But when I try to rename or delete it I get an error saying I don't have enough permissions:

```
> sftp test@myip
> rename test.txt new.txt
Couldn't rename file "/test.txt" to "/new.txt": Permission denied
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *"permissions to read, write and modify"* do not give you permissions to rename nor delete.

The renaming and deleting are considered operations with a parent directory, not with the file. So you need permissions to modify the parent directory. That's true both on Windows and *nix. It's not really SFTP question.